# vmware workstation shared vm remote connection

Tags: vmware-workstation

I'm running vmware workstation 9 on a dedicated server so I can connect to my virtual machines from a remote connection using workstation 9 as well.

I've gone ahead and shared the VM, but I've searched all over and can't seem to figure out how to connect to the shared vm.

What do you put as the Host/IP, user, pass? Is it of the shared vm, or the host vm?

Is there some other settings you need to do as well? I'm completely stumped. Most of the videos I see seem to be people using shared vm's on the same network, not a remote network.

Answer (score 1):

See: http://www.sysprobs.com/how-to-share-virtual-machines-in-vmware-workstation-and-access-from-remote-workstations "How to Access Shared VMs from Remote VMware Workstation"

In short,

**IP/Host:** The IP/Hostname is of the physical host.

**Credentials:** You can configure roles and permissions, but I believe it will also accept credentials from the Windows/Linux host (possibly, only the user running workstation, not sure)

> Most of the videos I see seem to be people using shared vm's on the same network, not a remote network.

As long as you can connect to the server (ie: ping it, access other services such as web, smb, …) you will be able to connect. You may need to forward ports (the port is configurable, but 443 by default), ssh tunnel, or join a VPN to access it remotely. (It might be painfully slow, but should get the job done.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be better off turning on remote desktop, or vnc, or some other remote control within the guest. You can then connect to that using a remote desktop client using the guest ip and login credentials.

If you can't connect to it put the network adapter in bridge mode instead of NAT, this may help. I don't think you can connect using workstation, an if you cam I dont know why you would want to.